# Acessing properties of an object in an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

So I've been trying to figure this one out for a while and I'm really hoping someone would be able to help

I'm creating an array and storing a list of objects in it like this.

```
    const heroPost = postList.filter(post => post.hero);
```

when I console log *heroPost* I get the following result.

[image]

I'm trying to access the url property in this object as follows.

```
    console.log(heroPost[0].url);
```

But I keep getting this undefined error.

[image]

I'm not really sure what's going wrong here. I am using an async function to get data from a database which I'm guessing might be a problem but I'm outputting data from the 'postList' in jsx which I've used to retrieve data into the 'heroPost' so I'm uncertain how it can be the problem. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:
This is the portion of the component that uses the 'postList' to render data. Which works fine.

```
                <div className="posts-container">
                {postList.map((post) => (
                    <div key={post.id} className="post">
                        <h3 className="post-title">{post.title}</h3>
                        <div className="post-info">
                            <p className="author">{post.author}</p>
                            <p className="timestamp">{post.author}</p>
                        </div>
                        <p className="content">{post.body}</p>
                        <img src={post.url} alt="" />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
```

What I'm trying to do now is to use the heroPost to render data into the hero section of the page as follows but it is still throwing the undefined error.

```
  <div className="hero">
                <img src={heroPost[0].url} alt="" />
            </div>
```

Thank you for all the comments and answers, I understand the problem now. Still don't really get why it works in the 'postList' instance and not here. Is there a way I can do this without directly trying to go to the file where I retrieve the data and add it into that function?

Comment: My guess is your array is empty intialyy. Try with optional chaining operator. `console.log(heroPost?[0]?.url);`

Comment: may be you try to access to the array before it will get the value, try
if(heroPost && heroPost.length > 0) console.log(heroPost[0].url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an async function to get the data, when the component that consists this code, renders for the first time, it will not have the data it needs to render the component.

Hence 'undefined'

You can resolve this issue by conditionally rendering the component. That is, render the component only after the data is available.

Since you haven't shared the component code, you can refer this react doc to help with the issue : [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Edit: following is how the condition would work. This is assuming postList is a state variable and a re-render will be triggered when it's value is changed:
[image: conditional rendering based on size of postList]

For the second snippet you shared:

```html
<div className="hero">
  {(heroPost && heroPost[0])?<img src={heroPost[0].url} alt="" />:'No data'}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would you happen to know how I can render this after the data has been retrieved and stored in the variable? I've edited the question with the component information as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on the new information. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  you get those error because it's undefined

If you look at you `console.log` you can see an empty array at the first line

That's because when you first render your component `postList` is an empty array.

Only after you fetch your data and populate you array you can access it

you can try to do this

```
useEffect(() => {
  setHeroPost(postList.find(p => p.hero))

}, [postList])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Didn't really work for me probably because It's still running in that instance where the data hasn't been retrieved yet. Trying to figure that out now.